# GeoServer CSS styles Submission Issue

Tags: geoserver, style, css, geoserver-css-module

I tried to add more than three rules of CSS styles, whenever I tried to add fourth rule, I can't submit the style in Geoserver 2.8.1.

Please find the CSS styles I used below.

```
/* Default Style less than a scale*/
*[@scale < 50000] {
   fill: #FFD9B3;
   fill-opacity: 50%;
   stroke: #D9D8D8;
   stroke-width: 0.5;
}

/* Default Style 2 */
[@scale >= 50000] [@scale < 250000]{
   fill: #FFCC99;
   fill-opacity: 50%;
   stroke: #E2E0DD;
   stroke-width: 0.5;
}

/* Filter police */
[name LIKE '%police%'] [@scale < 250000]{
   fill: #CDCDFE; 
   stroke: #CCCCCC;
   stroke-width: 0.5;
}

/* Filter hospital/clinic */
[name LIKE '%hospital%' or name LIKE '%clinic%'] [@scale < 250000]{
   fill: #FFCCCC;
   stroke: #DCA3A3;
   stroke-width: 0.5;
}

/* Filter Educational Institutes */
[name LIKE '%school%' or name LIKE '%college%' or name LIKE '%vidya%' or name LIKE '%university%'] [@scale < 250000]{
   fill: #FFD9B3;
   stroke: #c6b29F;
   stroke-width: 0.5;
}

/* Filter Stadium/Ground */
[name LIKE '%stadium%' or name LIKE '%ground%'] [@scale < 250000]{
   fill: #DFDF9F;
   stroke: #D4D4AA;
   stroke-width: 0.5;
}


/* Name Display */
[@scale < 35000]{
   label:[name];
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 12;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-fill: #9C9A9A;
   font-opacity: 0.8;

   label-anchor: 0.5 0.5;

   halo-radius: 1.5;
   halo-color: white;
   halo-opacity: 0.8;

   -gt-label-auto-wrap: 80;
}
```

Is there any code missing? and How can I solve this Issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you are overwhelming the translation engine with choices, please [read this for full details](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/css/cascading.html#understanding-css-to-sld-translation-in-cascading-mode) but the short answer is to add

```
@mode "Simple";
```

at the top of your styles to reduce the amount of simplification the translation engine tries to apply. You could also try the `Exclusive` mode but you will need to be patient (and probably increase the available memory in the JVM). If you upgrade to GeoServer 2.9 you can use the `Flat` option mentioned too.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is use of '**or**' inside the selector. You need to use '**,**' to imply **OR** in the sense you mean.

Whereas a space between indicators mean **AND**

See here for details about using selectors:
https://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/selectors/

**EDIT:**
Also you can tidy up and not have so many LIKE statements by using regex in the selector. 
For Example, to find where name is like *hospital* or name is like *clinic*:

```
[name =~'\bhospital|\bclinic']
```

Try the following instead:

```
/* Default Style less than a scale*/
*[@scale < 50000] {
   fill: #FFD9B3;
   fill-opacity: 50%;
   stroke: #D9D8D8;
   stroke-width: 0.5;
}

/* Default Style 2 */
[@scale >= 50000][@scale < 250000]{
   fill: #FFCC99;
   fill-opacity: 50%;
   stroke: #E2E0DD;
   stroke-width: 0.5;
}

/* Filter police */
[name LIKE '%police%'][@scale < 250000]{
   fill: #CDCDFE; 
   stroke: #CCCCCC;
   stroke-width: 0.5;
}

/* Filter hospital/clinic */
[name LIKE '%hospital%'][@scale < 250000],
[name LIKE '%clinic%'][@scale < 250000]{
   fill: #FFCCCC;
   stroke: #DCA3A3;
   stroke-width: 0.5;
}

/* Filter Educational Institutes */
[name LIKE '%school%'][@scale < 250000],
[name LIKE '%college%'][@scale < 250000],
[name LIKE '%vidya%'][@scale < 250000],
[name LIKE '%university%'][@scale < 250000]{
   fill: #FFD9B3;
   stroke: #c6b29F;
   stroke-width: 0.5;
}

/* Filter Stadium/Ground */
[name LIKE '%stadium%'][@scale < 250000],
[name LIKE '%ground%'][@scale < 250000]{
   fill: #DFDF9F;
   stroke: #D4D4AA;
   stroke-width: 0.5;
}


/* Name Display */
[@scale < 35000]{
   label:[name];
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 12;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-fill: #9C9A9A;
   font-opacity: 0.8;

   label-anchor: 0.5 0.5;

   halo-radius: 1.5;
   halo-color: white;
   halo-opacity: 0.8;

   -gt-label-auto-wrap: 80;
}
```